# How do I stop people from changing my name in cube2 sauerbraten?

Tags: cheats, ubuntu, cube-2-sauerbraten

I was playing cube2 Sauerbraten, when this someone started changing my name to vulgar things and making my guy say similar stuff.

What are they doing, and how can I stop them?  I am running ubuntu 21.10.